# Why do so many grammars divide a clause into Subject and Verb instead of Subject and Predicative?

Tags: verbs, sentences, clauses, grammatical-subject, predicatives

I used to start learning a few languages, admittingly my interest ,stamina and brain force didn't last for more than a couple of days each.

Nethertheless, I noticed , that the different grammars explained clauses being divided into Subject and Verbs as their minimal requirements.

Now, Subject is a sentence part and verb is a part of speach, furthermore other definitions of clauses name Subject and Predicative as the minimal requirements for a clause , which is a blessing feeling of absence of cognitive dissonance since in this case both are sentence parts.

But why is it so?

Comment: _Predicate_ is a [logical term](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). _Subject_ is a grammatical relation. _Verb_ is a lexical category, and [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) is a phrase that acts like a verb. These are different kinds of thing, and they don't pertain to the same contexts. Naturally, that means people can get confused when they use them all in the same context. That, and the fact that every grammar uses its own terminology in its own way, because every language works differently.

Comment: My fault, I meant predicative

Comment: But are there any grammars that do that?

Comment: I find the question perfectly valid. I myself found it confusing when I first heard the frequently used description "subject - verb - object word order" where two different concepts have been mixed up (although there is justification to this).

Comment: I did not make a clear distinction between modern grammars and traditional

Comment: But we **do** divide a clause into Subject and Predicate, the latter being realised by a verb phrase. "Predicate" is a **function** term, while "verb phrase" is a **category** term.

Comment: @BillJ Yep, but it depends on what terminology you subscribe to!